# I'm using ubuntu, django 3.0.5, sqlte3 ...Help!!! Thanks! running "python manage.py shell" in command line, it gives error:

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, web-development-server

i am learning django, 
I'm using python 3.8, django 3.0.5, sqlite 3
after running "python manage.py shell".

is this due to sqlite?

The Error i get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 99, in handle
    return getattr(self, shell)(options)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 35, in ipython
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 119, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 99, in handle
    return getattr(self, shell)(options)
  File "/home/hrishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 35, in ipython
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 119, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's manage.py file. I did not edit it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I didn't even edit this file. 
Help!!!

Comment: What is the output of `python -m pip list`?

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get install python-apt`. Even after installing python-apt `ModuleNotFound` appears then uninstall and install `python-apt`.

Comment: thanks for reply Klaus D/ pip list is displayed after running the command. Not able to paste complete o/p, Here;s the few initial lines     Package               Version            
--------------------- -------------------
alembic        0.9.3.dev0
apturl            0.5.2
asgiref           3.2.7
asn1crypto    0.24.0
attrs              19.3.0  
Automat        0.8.0 
Babel            2.4.0
backcall       0.1.0 bleach      3.1.0
blinker        1.4
Brlapi       0.6.6
bs4          0.0.1
certifi         2018.1.180.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
Django       3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

use "python3 manage.py runserver shell" command in ubantu